# Is it possible to compile Kotlin Native without runtime checks?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native

I couldn't find a list of compiler flags for the Kotlin compiler. I wanted to know if it is possible to compile Kotlin Native to "unsafe" code without Null check Range checks for arrays etc' in order to create code with less runtime overhead?
It is especially relevant for real-time systems. Is that a valid use case for Kotlin?

Comment: Real-time with a garbage collected language? What kind of real-time do you mean? I wouldn't suggest using it to pilot a missile or cool a nuclear power plant.

Comment: Kotlin-Native is a flavour that can run without garbage collector also.